# setup svn over https without apache

Tags: svn, nginx, https, lighttpd

I have tried to do this for months without success so I decided to finally ask if anyone has done it.

I am trying to setup svn over https without an apache web server. This can be done with git repositories, but couldn´t find the way to do it without apache for svn. I have lighttpd (could run nginx as well) but there isn´t a module to host svn repositories for either of those web servers, and it doesn´t seem to be a priority in their development.

The reason for me to want to do this is because my repositories are hosted on my router´s usb and my webserver is running in my router, and there isn´t a version of apache compiled for the router that can load modules (even if there were, it would probably perform poorly with so limited resources, but at least I would give it a try).
My temporary solution is to run apache on my pc, and forward the subdirectory /svn over to my apache running on that pc, but that requires the pc to be on whenever I need to access the repositories, and that´s what I am trying to avoid.

I know my setup is very specific, but if anyone has any idea on how to solve it, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Subversion does not support DAV protocol access with any web server than Apache httpd at this time.  There's been some talk of resolving that but nothing has been done on that front yet.

Comment: thank you for the answer. yes, it seems apache is still the only way to go for now